# How to remove Pandas rows which contain non English words using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, non-english

I want to remove rows (each row includes already tokenized sentence) which contains non-English word(s).
This example data set has more than three rows, I simplified the original data set for the brevity.

```
data = {
  "col1": [['apartment', 'expectations', 'insinuate', 'welcome'], ['très', 'réactive', 'arrangeante', 'notre','place'],['buena', 'ubicación','you']]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I tried using the below code but it only works for the version above 3.7.

```
#only works for the version above 3.7.
df[df.col1.map(lambda x: x.isascii())] 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isascii'
```

Is there an another way to address this issue to get the below output? 
Many thanks.

```
expected output:
                                            col1
0  [apartment, expectations, insinuate, welcome]
```

Comment: Have you tried the [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/) package? By the way, this package works much better on entire sentences than it does on single words.

Comment: Hi, the error message comes from the fact that you're applying map on a list, not a string. Still, searching for non ASCII values won't be enough to find english words.